# Neo4j troubleshooting steps?

Tags: neo4j

We have written a C# service to load data with indexes on the neo4j server. The load is pushed at a good speed at first but later slows down and the browser frequently dies. Can someone help me with the steps to exactly look into? Or steps to troubleshoot?

debug.log has only the queries nothing alarming
security.log no errors found
CPU : 4 cores
RAM : 50g

Have left the heap settings to default as it will auto calculate and do the required assignments.

Comment: how much data are you loading?
It is recommended to fix the heap size initially. Try setting the max and initial size both to same values (8-16GB). When this is not done, and the heap size grows, it leads to full garbage collection pauses which is basically a problem.
try monitoring the heap usage too to get an idea of how your query is affecting the heap usage.
If you are pushing a lot of data together, try pushing it in batches

Comment: You may want to EXPLAIN the query to confirm in the query plan that indexes are actually being used for the initial lookup. If you can't get a PROFILE plan (which has more useful profiling info but requires the query to execute to completion), the next step would be to share the query for analysis.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the Heap setting and the query plan.

Comment: The neostore.transaction.db.0-176 transaction log files keep filling the storage. It is safe to delete the files? it contains the transaction info only. The data should have been stored on node and relationship store. Do i need to be aware of anything as it doesn't affect backup.